# Remove build info from Camel logging

Tags: maven, apache-camel

Is it possible to omit the initial build info when logging the Camel output from Maven ? As it stands it prints out a hefty chunk of build and classpath info that we could do without in the logs.

Edit:

I'm running it via mvn camel:run and I've just discovered that if I append to a log file rather than to the console I don't see the build info at the beginning.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. How do you run your Camel application? Do you use mvn camel:run or something else?

Comment: mvn camel:run, I have updated the post above. For the time being I think logging it to a file rather than console will resolve our problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camel:run maven goal, is used the org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0 JAR, where it uses the AbstractMojo as the base class.

It uses the getLog() method on this base class for all its logging. So when it startup it does an INFO logging of the classpath, which is what you see on the console. In the RunMojo.java at line 621 you got it:

```
    getLog().info("Classpath = " + classpathURLs);
```

So I suggest to look for how to configure logging levels for Maven Plugins / Goals, when executing from the command line.

There is no Camel specific option to dictate this, as we use the AbstractMojo as base class for our Maven plugins, which is the intent of the AbstractMojo (to allow people to build custom maven goals)